# useRoute() to navigate from one page to another

Tags: nuxt3

I am using Nuxt3.

From within the `script` section of a page, how can I navigate to another page by using `useRoute()` (or something better)?

Comment: Tried this one? https://nuxt.com/docs/api/utils/navigate-to